# How to change Pending status to Paid status

Tags: api, shopify

I have a shop that accumulates many orders that are accepted without credit cards by using other payment methods. Hence they are recorded as Open, Pending orders. With the API I need to be able to create a new transaction that will change the status from Pending to Paid.

When I create a new transaction against a pending order with the kind set to 'capture' the API returns 403 forbidden, which kind of makes sense since it is meant to capture an authorized payment from a credit card.

Can you please add a transaction kind to the API allowing a change in status from pending to paid.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused by _Can you please add a transaction kind to the API allowing a change in status from pending to paid._ -- consider us more like your pals at the pub. You come to us asking advice. We dispense advice. We don't do your job for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 403 Forbidden should only be returned if you try to use another kind other than `capture`, or if you're actually not authorized to create Transactions. Double check the permissions on the app to make sure you have `write_orders` permissions. If you do, shoot Shopify an email with the app details for us to investigate further.